# mac trying to compile with -nostdinc

Tags: c++, g++

I am trying to do a "clean" build of a c++ program on my mac. By clean, I mean, do not include anything that I do not explicitly specify.

My gcc installation is located at:

```
/Applications/gcc471/
```

*So far*, I can compile using

```
-nostdinc++
```

by including

```
GPP-INCLUDES += -I/Applications/gcc471/include/c++/4.7.1/
GPP-INCLUDES += -I/Applications/gcc471/include/c++/4.7.1/x86_64-apple-darwin12.0.0
```

and doing

```
g++ -c *.cpp $(GPP-INCLUDES) -nostdinc++
```

I am pretty happy with that. However, I am trying to make the leap into compiling with

```
-nostdinc
```

And it seems that, no matter how many paths I include like

```
/usr/local/include
/usr/include
....
```

I get a crapton of errors like this:

```
/Applications/gcc471/include/c++/4.7.1/tr1/cmath: At global scope:
/Applications/gcc471/include/c++/4.7.1/tr1/cmath:156:11: error: ‘::double_t’ has not been declared
/Applications/gcc471/include/c++/4.7.1/tr1/cmath:157:11: error: ‘::float_t’ has not been declared
/Applications/gcc471/include/c++/4.7.1/tr1/cmath:160:11: error: ‘::acosh’ has not been declared
...
```

Does anyone know how to completely build a cpp program from scratch on the mac using -nostdinc?

Comment: Same issue here. Cross compiling on Linux host.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to compile using -nostdinc, but not without -I/usr/include/ as I had hoped. I do not trust Xcodes llvm/clang/gcc4.2  (Really old)/not real GCC nonsense. So I downloaded GCC from scratch and built it from source using the guide here: http://staticimport.blogspot.ca/2012/02/building-gcc-462-on-os-x-lion.html

The problem is that libstdc does not appear to ship with gcc anymore, only libstdc++. So all .hpp files are in my GCC directory, but really old headers, such as locale.h (From 1993), only appears to come with the libstdc XCode installs to /usr/include. I will keep looking for a vanilla libstdc to install, but for now, these are the most minimal and most "GNU" directories I can include to compile:

```
...
#FOR -nostdinc++ 
GPP-INCLUDES += -I/Applications/gcc471/include/c++/4.7.1/
GPP-INCLUDES += -I/Applications/gcc471/include/c++/4.7.1/x86_64-apple-darwin12.0.0
#for -nostdinc
GPP-INCLUDES += -I/Applications/gcc471/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.0.0/4.7.1/include/
GPP-INCLUDES += -I/usr/local/include
GPP-INCLUDES += -I/usr/include/ #bahhhhh cant get away

g++ -c *.cpp $(GPP-INCLUDES) -nostdinc++ -nostdinc  -std=c++11
```

Comment: Does this also work if you used `-I/someotherlocaldir/usr/include/`?